# Existence of continuous norm on C(X)

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space, and $C(X)$ the space of continuous functions. Is there a continuous norm (as function to $\mathbb{R}$)  on $C(X)$? The topology is given by the family of seminorms (locally convex): 
$$ ||f||_K = \sup_{x \in K} \left| f(x) \right|  $$ where $K \in X$ is compact.

I know that if the space $X$ is compact, then we have the norm. But how to prove that it is not in other case?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions, with one of them well-defined.  The first being whether or not there is a norm which generates the same topology as the one furnished by the family of seminorms.  The second being whether or not a particular function (which you have not given) is a norm.  For this question, what function $\|\cdot\|:C(X)\to\mathbb R$ would you consider?

Comment: @Aweygan, I asked about the existence of any norm as a function. No matter what topology it would generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb N$ with the usual metric. Then $C(X)$ can be identified with $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}$ and the topology you are considering is the topology of convergence at each point, i.e. the product topology. It is well known that there is no norm for this topology.

Comment: ...because every continuous seminorm on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is dominated by a seminorm of the form $q(x)=\max\{|x_1,\ldots,|x_N|\}$ and thus has a huge kernel.

Comment: Thank's, but I asked about the existence of any norm as a function from topological space $C(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} (\mathbb{C})$. No matter what kind of topology it generates

Comment: There is always a norm on any vector space. You mentioned a particular topology in the statement and I proved that there is no norm for that topology. Every vector space is isometric, as a vector space, to a subspace of a Hilbert space so there is a norm and even an inner product on every vector space. However, it may not be easy to define a norm explicitly.